# I am using glmnet to address the multicollinearity issue, and for best lambda i want to calculate VIF between variables

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, glmnet

I am using glmnet and for the best lambda I want to check the VIF between variables. Can anyone suggest how can I accomplish this?

Below is the code I am following and **fielddfm** is the data frame containing the independent variables:

```
x<- model.matrix(depvar ~ ., fielddfm) [,-1]
y <- depvar
lambda <- 10^seq(10, -2, length = 100)
ridge.mod <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, lambda = lambda)
predict(ridge.mod, s = 0, exact = T, type = 'coefficients')
cv.out <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, nfolds = 3)
bestlam <- cv.out$lambda.min
ridge.pred <- predict(ridge.mod, s = bestlam, newx = x)
predict(ridge.mod, type = "coefficients", s = bestlam)'
```

Here, I get the coefficients for different promotion vehicles but I want to know, VIF values for the best lambda for different independent variables

Could yo please suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please include the output of `dput(fielddfm)` in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Since a) VIF is a function of your predictors rather than your model and b) a ridge regression keeps all variables irrespective of lambda, you could get the VIFs from an arbitrarily-fitted linear model. For example:

```
vifs = car::vif(lm(y ~ ., data = X))
```

where `y` is your response and `X` is your dataframe of predictors. Note that the results are independent of the values contained in `y`.

Given the above however, It's a little dubious whether this question makes sense in the first place...